# GPG error The following signatures couldn't be verified: NO_PUBKEY 1E9377A2BA9EF27F

Tags: node.js, windows, vagrant, virtualbox

I am using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/) on windows 10.My environment conditions are:

1-[Node v4.6.0](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

2-[Vagrant 5.1](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/)

3-[Virtualbox 1.9](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html)

I want to to get [Thimble](https://github.com/mozilla/thimble.mozilla.org) working locally.

when i use command

```
vagrant up & vagrant reload provision OR vagrant provision
```

it is giving me error as 
[image]

My issue's background is described [Here.](https://github.com/mozilla/thimble.mozilla.org/issues/1601)

All the solutions i saw for this are related to linux environment like using command like this etc.

```
 apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 1E9377A2BA9EF27F
```

which can't be used in windows environment.So kindly give suggestions according to windows environment.

Comment: the solution to run the command in the ubuntu VM, not from your windows environment

Comment: i know i have mentioned that this type of linux based solutions can be found but no windows based can be seen.